# Transactional email variables for product attributes

Tags: email, product-attribute, transactional

I want to edit a transactional email which is used for product returns. The current table columns all work, but I want to add in some additional product attributes, specifically ones in my store which are named "ref_color" and "ref_size".

I'm thinking it might be something like

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getProductRef_color()) ?>
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getProductRef_size()) ?>
```

Here's what is already there from the .phtml file:

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <strong><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getProductName()) ?></strong>
        <?php $_options = $item->getOptions();
            if($_options): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
        <?php foreach ($_options as $_option) : ?>
            <dt><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_option['label']) ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo $_option['value'] ?></dd>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </dl>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getProductSku()) ?></span>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getOptionAttributeStringValue($item->getCondition())) ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getStatusLabel()) ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($item->getProduct()->getProductRefColor()) ?>
```